# Modify a global variable or parse all host variables for a condition

Tags: ansible

I need to modify a global variable or parse all host variables for a condition.

What I was hoping for:

- Set a global variable in group_vars - "commit_success: true"
- For each host, make and "commit" a change.
- Each host reverts the change if no "confirm commit" is received in X min.
- Check each host's functionality.  If a failure is found, "set_fact: commit_success=false"
- Only if all hosts have "commit_success=true", do not confirm commit ANY host (in order to prevent them reverting)

group_vars/all.yaml

```
commit_success: true
```

Checks if the host's configuration was successfully applied.  If there is 1 or more failures, change that host's commit_success variable to false

```
    - name: Compare Each Snapshot
      when: 
        - snap_check.total_failed >= 1
      set_fact: 
        commit_success: false
```

This will not commit changes on hosts that failed, but I don't want to commit to ANY any node even if just a single node fails.  Its all or nothing.

```
    - name: Confirm Commit
      when: 
        - commit_success
      juniper_junos_config:
        provider:  "{{ credentials }}"
        config_mode: "{{ netconf.mode }}"
        commit: true
        comment: "{{ netconf.comment }}"
        commit_empty_changes: false
```

My result is this, when 4 nodes do not pass the check.

```
ok: [d01-bbrj01] => {
    "commit_success": true
}
ok: [d03-bbrj03] => {
    "commit_success": true
}
ok: [d02-bbrj02] => {
    "commit_success": true
}
ok: [d04-bbrj04] => {
    "commit_success": true
}
ok: [d05-bprj01] => {
    "commit_success": true
}
ok: [d06-bprj02] => {
    "commit_success": true
}
ok: [d07-dsrj01] => {
    "commit_success": false
}
ok: [d08-dsrj02] => {
    "commit_success": false
}
ok: [d09-dsrj03] => {
    "commit_success": false
}
ok: [d10-dsrj04] => {
    "commit_success": false
}
```

Again, I either want to modify the global variable, or I want to check that ALL host's "commit_success: true" before I confirm commit.

Comment: so, basically you want a global global_commit_success variable and set its value to true if all the "local" commit_success variables (as in your last snippet of your question) are all true ?

Comment: That's correct.  The alternative is to use a globally defined variable, that will be changed if any host fails.  Else, it will not be changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, I think the solution is simple. Set a `commit_success` individually for each host. We don't need a global one:

```
- name: Set commit_success
  set_fact: 
    commit_success: "{{ snap_check.total_failed == 0 }}"
```

Note that we've dropped the `when` condition here so that every host
will have a `commit_success` fact.

On the host that will be running the `juniper_junos_config` task, we set a final variable by iterating over the hosts from the previous task:

```
    - set_fact:
        all_commit_success: "{{ all_commit_success|default(true)|bool and hostvars[item].commit_success }}"
      loop: "{{ groups.devices }}"
```

We can now use this conditional in the `juniper_os_config` task:

```
    - name: Confirm Commit
      when: 
        - all_commit_success
      juniper_junos_config:
        provider:  "{{ credentials }}"
        config_mode: "{{ netconf.mode }}"
        commit: true
        comment: "{{ netconf.comment }}"
        commit_empty_changes: false
```